# Concatenar dentro de Range Object

Tags: vba

Estoy tratando de concatenar una variable a un rango.

```
Dim i As Integer
    i = 1

    If Range("H+i") = "Validacion Expediente" Then
        MsgBox ("y") 
    Else   
        MsgBox ("N")
```

esto con el fin de saber si las celdas que estan en la columna H tienen como nombre Validacion Expediente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya resolvi el problema, la respuesta es:

```
Dim i As Integer
i = 1

If Range("H" & i) = "Validacion Expediente" Then
    MsgBox ("y") 
Else  
    MsgBox ("N")
```